# How to get period after footnote without flushing left (i.e. Chicago-style footnotes without Chicago bib)

Tags: footnotes

Apologies if this is answered already. I can't find the answer anywhere.

Right now, my footnotes look like this:
[image]

I would like them to look like this, i.e. to not be superscript & to have a period after them, as here: [image]

My understanding is that Chicago-style produces this footnote style, but I would like to have this footnote style *without* using biblatex or Chicago.

What I've found only gives me this (using `\deffootnote{2em}{2em}{\thefootnotemark.\enskip}`):
[image]

Thank you in advance for any help/guidance!

A MWE:

```
\documentclass[reqno, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{verbatim} %gives a begin{comment} enviro 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,enumitem} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{scrextend} %customize footnotes
\usepackage[hyphens]{url} %breaks up URL's to prevent overfull hbox 
\usepackage{lipsum}

%Fonts and Sections 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%%FOOTNOTE
%\deffootnote{2em}{2em}{\thefootnotemark.\enskip} %gives period and alignment... 
\makeatletter
\makeatother

\begin{document} 
    \title{TITLE}
    \author{} 
    \date{}
    \maketitle

\section{Test}
Testing testing testing\footnote{Test footnote. Let's see what this looks like. Let's see what it looks like when it's even longer, to see how it looks on two lines.}. TEST TEST EST.\footnote{Testing again.}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this much more simply than your own answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{\parindent 1.8em\@thefnmark.~#1}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Filler text.\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.}
Filler text.\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out my partner is -- unbeknownst to me -- a footnote expert.

This is what he came up with:

```
\makeatletter

% % footnote modification: must be between \makeatletter and \makeatother

\renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{%
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
 
  \begin{list}{}{\setlength{\labelwidth}{0mm}% indents footnote text 
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
    \setlength{\labelsep}{3pt}% moves footnote mark to the left
     \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
      \setlength{\topsep}{-3pt}% removes separation between footnotes
    \footnotesize}%
  \item[\hspace{1em} \@thefnmark.\hfill]#1% @makefnmark
  \end{list}%
}
%      \setlength{\footnotesep}{0pt}%

\makeatother
```

Sharing in case this helps someone out.

Also, neither of us is quite sure what the following commands do, so if anyone has guidance on that, that'd be useful knowledge:

```
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
     \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
```

Same with the \hfill toward the end.